# Something unrecognize in template function working with a template object

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Gcc (4.7.2) throws a little error compiling this code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct test
{
    template<int n>
    int select() const
    {
        return n;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct test_wrapper
{
    void print() const
    {
        std::cout << t.select<3>() << std::endl; // L.18
    }

    test<T> t;
};

int main()
{}
```

And the error is:

```
test3.cpp: In member function 'void test_wrapper<T>::print() const':
test3.cpp:18:34: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
```

If I change `test<T> t` by a specialized type, for example `test<void> t`, this error dissapear.

Where is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the `template` keyword when calling a template method inside a templated construct:

```
t.template select<3>();
```